# Java syntax explanation - getMenuInflater()

Tags: java, android, syntax

Just downloaded android studio, and I am using big nerd ranch's guide to android programming to learn the ropes.

When you start android studio this code is already in the main activity file:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    **getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);**
    return true;
}
```

I don't understand the `getMenuInflater` line. In my short experience with java only an object comes before a method when using a period to separate the two such as in `dog.bark()`. Here it looks like the line means call the inflate method which is defined within the getMenuInflater method. However, I checked the source code for `getMenuInflater()`, and there is no inflate method in its body.

Can somebody demystify the syntax in this line for me?

Comment: getMenuInflater() returns an object so you can use it instead of an object

Comment: interesting... that probably broke it down the best for me. thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);` is a short form of this:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu)
```

Comment: lol now I have another question. how do you set an object reference variable equal to a method? Such as in MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater()

Comment: you are not setting a method, you are setting the result of calling the method getMenuInflater(), in this case a MenuInflater object

Answer (score 2):

You are extending an activity and android studio adds that line for you to configure the menu for the layout, below is actual implementation of the method in the activity class :

```
 public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
            // Make sure that action views can get an appropriate theme.
            if (mMenuInflater == null) {
                initWindowDecorActionBar();
                if (mActionBar != null) {
                    mMenuInflater = new MenuInflater(mActionBar.getThemedContext(), this);
                } else {
                    mMenuInflater = new MenuInflater(this);
                }
            }
            return mMenuInflater;
        }
```

Comment: Hmm... Where does inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu) play into all that?

Comment: you inflate the menu like you inflate the activity with xml layout , you add the menu item through a xml under /menu folder

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're confused on, but I believe you think that you have to have a method call always after the name of an object. That's basically true, (except for static methods) so you can think of the call like

```
this.getMenuInflater()
```

This is a keyword in Java referring to the current object invoking the method

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am aware the answer is accepted. 
But I think, I can provide a little bit insight and obtain a little bit of healthy criticism :
The MenuInflater is an *Android system resource*. It is created when the android boots up. It is a persistent object and the reference to it is always available in memory. 
Every subclass of Context class *i.e. Activity* in your case, can obtain the reference to it, by calling:

1. `getMenuInflater()` from within the class(Example: **Context**) or any of its subclass(Ex: **Activity**)
2. `<any_context_object>.getMenuInflater()` from outside the class.

## Internally:

`getMenuInflater()` checks if a MenuInflater object exists in memory and then :

- If it does exist in memory , it returns the object.
- Otherwise, it creates one, and returns it.

It is called a Singleton design pattern and ensures that one and only one instance of a class is created. In doing so, you can reuse the state of the old object and share that state across multiple processes without explicitly passing it to them.

So, Android Runtime creates one MenuInflater object and applications can ask for it by calling the getMenuInflater() method defined on the context object.

```java
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    // Make sure that action views can get an appropriate theme.
    if (mMenuInflater == null) {
        initWindowDecorActionBar();
        if (mActionBar != null) {
            mMenuInflater = new MenuInflater(mActionBar.getThemedContext(), this);
        } else {
            mMenuInflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        }
    }
    return mMenuInflater;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will something like a menu will be automatically created in the Res folder named as menu.xml,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item android:id="@+id/slideshowbutton"
      android:icon="@drawable/settings"
      android:title="@string/settings"/>

<item android:id="@+id/editbutton"
      android:icon="@drawable/adduser"
      android:title="@string/adduser"/>

<item android:id="@+id/cropbutton"
      android:icon="@drawable/message"
      android:title="@string/message"/>

<item android:id="@+id/detailsbutton"
      android:icon="@drawable/logout"
      android:title="@string/Logout"/>
```

you can add the menu list as you want

The menu will be looking like
[image]